# Prove that this system of subsets is a $\sigma$ algebra

Tags: measure-theory

$X = A \cup B$ and $\mathfrak{A}(\mathfrak{B}$, respectively) is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $A$ ($B$, respectively). Prove that
$$\mathfrak{D} = \{E\cup F:E\in \mathfrak{A}, F \in \mathfrak{B}\}$$ is a $\sigma$ algebra of subsets from $X$.

It's not difficult to show that $X$, $\emptyset \in \mathfrak{D}$. I find it more challenging, however, to show that any countable union of $C_n \in \mathfrak{D}$ lies in $\mathfrak{D}$.

Comment: Maybe you need to assume $A,B$ to be disjoint.

Answer (score 0):

So, for each $n$ there exist $E_n$ and $F_n$ such that $E_n \in \mathfrak{A}, F_n  \in \mathfrak{B}$ and $C_n = E_n\cup F_n$

So $$\bigcup C_n = \underbrace{(\bigcup E_n)}_{\in\mathfrak{A} }\cup  \underbrace{(\bigcup F_n)}_{\in\mathfrak{B} }\in \mathfrak{D } $$

Comment: @greenoid, thank you. It seems that I need a bit more help. For any $C \in \mathfrak{D}$,  $C^c$ should also be in $\mathfrak{D}$. 
$C^c = (E \cup F)^c = E^c \cap F^c$. Given that completion is taken over $X$, it doesn't seem obvious that this set $\in \mathfrak{D}$. Can you please help?

Comment: Is there any other assumption about $A$ and $B$